# C# assuming floating point literals are of type double?

Tags: c#

I'm following along in my C# textbook and it says that "C# assumes that all floating point literals are of type double." I get what this is saying, but I'm not quite sure how to apply the fix to the example program I am working on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CoinCounter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int quarters;
            int dimes;
            int nickels;
            int pennies;
            float myTotal = 0F;

            Console.Out.WriteLine("How many quarters are in the jar?");
            quarters = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());

            Console.Out.WriteLine("How many dimes are in the jar?");
            dimes = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());

            Console.Out.WriteLine("How many nickels are in the jar?");
            nickels = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());

            Console.Out.WriteLine("How many pennies are in the jar?");
            pennies = int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine());

            myTotal = (quarters * .25) + (dimes * .10) + (nickels  * .05) + (pennies * .01);
            Console.Out.Write("\nTotal: " + myTotal.ToString("c"));

            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It comes back saying: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'." When I try to put that whole myTotal line is parenthesis and add an F to the end is says it's looking for a ';'.

So my question is, how do I use float? How can I add an F on the end of this? I've also tried casting (float) in front of it in different ways.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The language won't *implicitly* perform the conversion, because it results in a loss of precision. However, you can *explicitly* perform the conversion using a cast:

```
myTotal = (float)(
              (quarters * .25)
            + (dimes    * .10)
            + (nickels  * .05)
            + (pennies  * .01)
          );
```

In this case, you know that you're not dealing with astronomical quantities or exquisitely high precision, so this should be fine.

You could also prevent the automatic promotion of values to double by specifying floating point literals instead of doubles:

```
myTotal = (quarters * .25F)
        + (dimes    * .10F)
        + (nickels  * .05F)
        + (pennies  * .01F);
```

...the `int` variables will be promoted to `float` for the addition operation, so you'll have a `float` instead of a `double` type as the result.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer! You mentioned preventing automatic promotion. Is all that is just the difference between casting the whole equation to float versus each grouping or is there something more to that? Could you give an example where you would want to prevent automatic promotion? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Numeric promotions (C#) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691328%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 11):

You have a way bigger problem here. **You should never represent financial quantities as a float or a double**. C# has a type specifically designed to represent financial quantities: decimal.

Your code should be

```
decimal myTotal = 0.00m;
...
myTotal = (quarters * .25m) + (dimes * .10m) + (nickels  * .05m) + (pennies * .01m);
```

The way to remember this: "m is for money".

Also, while we're at it, use TryParse when converting user input to numbers; users might type something that is not a number, and then you'll get an exception.

Comment: +1 Since it's a homework assignment this would seem to be a trivial use but I agree with you that it doesn't hurt to establish good habits early on.

Comment: +1 Very good observation here - one that I completely missed.

Comment: + 1 I'm glad I came back and read this. Thank you for the tips. I had no idea TryParse even existed, I come from C++. Everything there was try/catch. Thanks! And yeah, I knew about the decimal type but like the others said, it seemed trivial for coin counting homework. Thanks again =]

Answer (score 1):

```
myTotal = (quarters * .25f) + (dimes * .10f) + (nickels  * .05f) + (pennies * .01f);
```

This should do it.
Multiplying an int with a float => a float result
In your version, int * double (default) => double results => double total.
Try to assign that to a float var, the compiler complains that double to float conversion has to be explicit (loss of precision).